Nuxt v.3.11 - How to Import `github/relative-time-element`?
I am experiencing issues when trying to use github/relative-time-element with Nuxt 3.11.2 and Nitro 2.9.6.
Here's what I've done so far:

I installed the library using: $ npm install @github/time-elements.
I configured nuxt.config.ts as follows:

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ...
  vue: {
      compilerOptions: {
      isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.startsWith('relative-time')
      }
  },
  ...
})


I also attempted to create a simple component components/atom/TimeRelative.vue:

<script setup>
// TimeRelative.vue
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import '@github/time-elements/dist/relative-time-element.js';

onMounted(() => {
    
});

const props = defineProps({
    time: String,
    class: String
});

</script>
<template>
<ClientOnly>
<relative-time datetime="2014-04-01T16:30:00-08:00" tense="past" format="relative"  prefix="this happened on">
  April 1, 2014
</relative-time>
</ClientOnly>
</template>

This results in an error saying that the package can't be found:  (it exists)
 ERROR  Internal server error: Missing "./dist/relative-time-element.js" specifier in "@github/time-elements" package                           3:49:06 PM
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: /.../components/atoms/TimeRelative.vue


If I try importing the file using:

import '~/node_module/@github/time-elements/dist/relative-time-element.js';

it doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't do anything — the HTML is rendered as if the component wasn't transformed at all.
What is the correct way to include this package in Nuxt 3?
Thanks!

Sorry,
my folder in node_modules is: node_modules/@github/time-elements
so the import should be:
import '@github/time-elements';

it works. Thanks!

The node_modules/@github folder contains the relative-time-element folder, so the correct import is:
import '@github/relative-time-element';
I checked - it works.

[12:24:39 PM] ERROR Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "@github/relative-time-element" from "components/atoms/TimeRelative.vue". Does the file exist?
I have uninstalled and reinstalled npm. Nothing seems to work. Are you adding something to nuxt.config.ts?
